# Formatting cells based on upcoming date in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format a cell to be highlighted red if the following conditions are true:

- the future date associated with that row (which is in a separate cell) is less than 21 days from today, **and**
- the cell (which is the one I want to format) contains "no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the dates are in column A, beginning with row 2, and cells to be formatted are in column B. Then you'd use conditional formatting with custom formula

```
=AND(A2<TODAY()+21, B2="no")
```

applying it to the range B2:B.